# Variable of type referenced from scope, but it is not defined. Error to compare string in QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

Yeah, I know that there are many questions of this subject open and answered in stackoverflow, but none solved my problem.

I'm trying to compare two strings in where clause of QueryOver, but I had the error “variable '' of type '' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined”. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and didn't find an example for my case. Can anyone help me?

That's my code:

```
var queryOverPaciente = _session.QueryOver(() => pacienteAlias).
    Where(() => pacienteAlias.DataCadastro.Value.IsBetween(dataInicio).And(dataFinal));


// Other things....

// the error occurs here. "Identificacao" and "MatriculaInicio" are strings 
// and I want to select all registers that "Identificacao" >= "MatriculaInicio".

queryOverPaciente = queryOverPaciente.Where(p => 
     p.Identificacao.CompareTo(filtroRelatorio.MatriculaInicio) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement *(the issue above)*

```
queryOverPaciente = queryOverPaciente
    .Where(p => p.Identificacao.CompareTo(filtroRelatorio.MatriculaInicio) >= 0);
```

representing comparison defined in C# as `string.CompareTo(`**`VALUE`**`)`:

> - Condition Less than zero This instance precedes **VALUE**.
> - Zero This instance has the same position in the sort order as **VALUE**.
> - Greater than zero This instance follows **VALUE**.-or- **VALUE** is null.

so these are *sort of* equal:

```
// negative means preceeds
string.CompareTo(`**`VALUE`**`) >= 0
// we only want follows or equals
string >= VALUE
```

and with SQL, we can express it directly:

```
column >= @VALUE
```

Back to our NH/C# solution. We can define it like this

```
queryOverPaciente
    .UnderlyingCriteria
     // GeProperty will generate >=
    .Add(Restrictions.GeProperty(
        // column
        Projections.Property(nameof(pacienteAlias.Identificacao)),
        // constant
        Projections.Constant(filtroRelatorio.MatriculaInicio)
    ));
```

A curiosity - to handle even the NULL as stated in C# definition above, we can for example add `ISNULL` statement *(more general and suitable `COALESCE` in fact)*

```
// use the Identificacao if filter is null
var isNull = Projections.SqlFunction("Coalesce"
    , NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String
    , Projections.Constant(filtroRelatorio.MatriculaInicio)
    , Projections.Property(nameof(pacienteAlias.Identificacao))
);

queryOverPaciente
    .UnderlyingCriteria
    .Add(Restrictions.GeProperty(
        Projections.Property(nameof(pacienteAlias.Identificacao)),
        // the ISNULL projection instead of constant
        isNull
    ));
```